# Undefined reference to `main' and _sbrk - startup code in own static library

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm, undefined-reference

I'm working on a Cortex-M4 (STM32F4-Discovery board), using the GNU ARM Embedded toolchain (gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q2). The hardware dependent part of my code (HAL-lib, CMSIS, startup etc.) is built in a static library, which I try to link to my application code. My application code contains a `main` symbol and my library contains a `_sbrk` symbol. These are the error messages:

```
engine_control/source/os/release/libkosmos-arm-stm32f4-discovery.a(_startup.o): In function `_start': 
_startup.c:(.after_vectors+0x9a): undefined reference to `main'
```

and:

```
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.4.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7e-m/fpu/libc_nano.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r': 
sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
```

I assume there is something wrong with my link order. Here is my link command:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Os -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -Werror -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal -T mem.ld -T libs.ld -T sections.ld -nostartfiles -Xlinker --gc-sections -L"config/linker" --specs=nano.specs -L/home/tkl/git/engine_control/source/os/release -Wl,-Map,"/home/tkl/git/engine_control/release/map/arm/release/.map" -lkosmos-arm-stm32f4-discovery -o "/home/tkl/git/engine_control/release/execute/arm/release/.elf"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you actually linking? Where is `main` _supposed_ to be? That link command seems to contain but one library and no object files...

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right. I missed linking my main object (because I unfortunately used different variable names for defining objects and using objects in my makefile ;) .

Answer (score 0):

Note if you put startup code into a library, the linker has probably no good reason to pull it in - Nobody is asking for it because typically no other part of code calls it - Stuff that you want in your image at any cost like startup code **needs to be** in an object file during the linking. And that object file should probably come first on your link line (because it typically calls `main` and all other sorts of symbols and those need to come *after* it in the link order in order to properly resolve the symbol).

The other one is `sbrk_r` complaining about no reference to `sbrk` - I would assume both of those are in your library. This might be resolved by running your library through `ranlib` to create a proper index.

Comment: Genuine curiosity: assuming there's actually a linker script being passed as one of the input files, would explicit symbol references in that (i.e. placing the entry point, exception vectors, etc. that probably are in that startup code) not count as references from the 'searching libraries' perspective?

Comment: If you tell the linker you want a specific symbol at a specific address, then yes. But the OP didn't present one (to us). If there's not much more than segment names and the addresses you want them in the linker script (perfectly valid when you try to use a generic one, and what I normally do), then no.

Comment: And if the startup code is made of multiple objects, I find partial linking very handy.